# Increment database field within jQuery IF Statement

Tags: jquery, database, if-statement, sql-update

I'm creating a website where a user answers questions on mathematics. I have if statements in my jQuery script to determine if the answer is correct.

Simplified pseudocode to give the general idea:

```
 If total = txt_total.val {
    // answer is correct
 } else if total != txt_total.val {
    // answer is incorrect
 }
```

Well, my question is this.. How could I increment a field in my database within these if statements (ie. If the user answers correctly, increment 'correct' field where user_id = user_id)

I believe it may involve Ajax somehow? I'm seeing stuff on updating a database field from clicking a button but not much on updating a database field within a jQuery if statement. Any help or even a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Go with jQuery ajax function. It is easy enough, you just have to have some kind of code on the back end to receive the data (just like a POST/GET to your server) and register that in your database.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You can use this shorthand in your case:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/